# How do I connect a bass guitar to my iPad to use with Garage Band

Tags: ios, ipados, garageband

Garage Band for iOS has a mode to use real instruments. The documentation is unclear, however, how to connect those instruments to the iOS device. What options exist to connect an electric bass guitar to an iOS device to use with Garage Band?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help?
http://www.musicradar.com/news/guitars/6-easy-ways-to-connect-your-guitar-to-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-516544
Or even more specific:
https://gigaom.com/2013/02/09/four-ways-to-connect-your-instrument-to-garageband/
Or you meant something different?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using iRig from IK Multimedia. It works great, and is a quite cheap solution.

[IK Multimedia Website](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irig/)

Comment: Can you tell me more how this works for you? What do you plug into what?

Comment: These links, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6z87yQaV4Vg or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcysqbWD5YM explains it quite well... Don't expect to have studio quality sound, but it works great for practicing.